# How to restrict flutter Textfield or TextFormField to accept only english language?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to restrict flutter Textfield or TextFormField to accept only english language ?? No other language should be allowed to enter.

Comment: Do you mean A to Z or a to z characters only?

Answer (score 7):

Try with this

```
TextField(
  inputFormatters: [
            FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("^[\u0000-\u007F]+\$"))
    ])
```

Or you can try with this if you want only english character.

```
 TextField(
   inputFormatters: [
            FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[a-zA-Z]"))
       ])
```

Comment: it works fine with me

Answer (score 3):

```
TextField(
    inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
       FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[a-z A-Z 0-9]'))
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions of english

```
bool validEnglish(String value) { 
  RegExp regex = RegExp(r'/^[A-Za-z0-9]*$'); 
  return (!regex.hasMatch(value)) ? false : true; 
}

TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter text',
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
               validator: (text) {
                if (text == null || text.isEmpty || !validEnglish(text)) {
                  return 'Text is empty or invalid' ;
                }
                return null;
              },
            )
```